In Godot, how do I attach scripts to specific tiles in a TileSetAtlasSource?
I have a TileSet with a TileSetAtlasSource.  Many of my tiles in it both 1) need custom scripts, and 2) have alternative tiles associated with them.  If I just needed scripts, I'd add them to a TileSetScenesCollectionSource (and have done so with some sprites).  If I only needed alternative tiles, it would be trivial to use TileSetAtlasSource as that is its purpose.
However, since I need both, what I have been doing thus far is:

create a separate scene for each tile that needs a script
give each scene a static add_to_map function that searches for its particular source id/atlas id given the passed TileMapLayer (I'm using Godot 4.3)
in the scene containing the TileMapLayers, call all possible scripted tiles' add_to_map against all TileMapLayers
add_to_map then adds a child to the TileMapLayer at the associated tile's position

This seems cumbersome for something that surely can't be that uncommon.
Thus far, all of my alternate tiles have been rotated versions of the original tile.  If there is a simple way to set properties on a tile added to a TileSetScenesCollectionSource and easily click and paint them to a TileMapLayer in the GUI, that would also a good solution.  My (brief) research indicates that's not an option.
